# CK-Editor in django not working in production

Tags: django, ckeditor

CK-editor works fine in development but its not working in production.

In the console tab it shows error:
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) ckeditor.js`

Comment: Looks like Static file deployment gone wrong

Comment: all other static files load good. I have also done ```python manage.py collectstatic```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's happening because your static file was handled wrongly or not handled for deployment.

Make sure your `setting.py` is look like this:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'YOUR STATIC FILE FOLDERS')]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

If you run your application on `Nginx or` apache2`please make sure you configured the`.conf` file properly to server the static files.

Also, there is ta straightforward and easy solution, that is `whitenoise`

If you don't want to serve your static files with Nginx or a similar server.

You can try `whitenoise`

To use whitenoise, please install it first and update your settings.py file like this:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

and add this in middlware before the sessionmiddleware

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware', # Serve static in production without nginx or apache
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    ........
]
```

Hope the solution will solve your ckeditor problem

Here you go for whitenoise docs: http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/

Comment: The ```settings.py``` is configured the same. 
And while I try to use whitenoise, it says ```Error running WSGI application``` ```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'whitenoise'``` ( I have done ```pip install whitenoise``` that too inside the venv.)

Comment: I think whitenoise not installed properly.

Here you go: http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/

Comment: Yes it worked for me, but I was getting `ValueError: Missing staticfiles manifest entry for filename.css`, then I removed the above line STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage', then it worked as expected.

Comment: Good to know it's working. The error you are getting currently coz, some files missing.  You can solve it another way, that whitenoise has another class that doesnt manifest static files, You can use that one

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue. Everything was working well in localhost but after I deployed the code to a live server django-ckeditor was not working. When I inspected the console, django-ckeditor was configured to check /static/ckeditor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js. But after configuring ckeditor and running python manage.py collecstatic for the first time, ckeditor is configured to copy the static files into the location given by STATIC_ROOT which staticfiles, and below is my static files settings which I believe is the way ALMOST everyone does it:

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'static'
]
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'staticfiles'
```

Looking at the above settings, there is a conflict here. The ckedtor static files will be copied to /staticfiles/ckeditor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js but Django will be looking into /static/ckeditor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js.

The simple hack I did was to copy all the ckeditor files into the static folder, commit the changes, and pullthe changes into my server and everything starts to work fine.

You don't need whitenoise to make it work if you are not using white noise already.

Answer (score 1):

collectstatic worked for me.

```
#command to collect static files
python3 manage.py collectstatic
```